# Using regex to split string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to split my string so that "Hello the cost 12.50 Hello this item is 7.30" would become ["Hello the cost is 12.50", "Hello this item is 7.30"]. I started off by first finding in the string what matches the 12.50 and 7.30 (floats), but can't seem to figure out how to split it by that number.

Comment: Hi Danielle. Welcome to SO. Can you add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve], please.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex pattern `(.*? \d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*`, and find all matches:

```js
var re = /(.*? \d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*/g;
var s = 'Hello the cost 12.50 Hello this item is 7.30';
var m;

do {
    m = re.exec(s);
    if (m) {
        console.log(m[1]);
    }
} while (m);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a RegExp you are looking for:

```js
'The price is 9.50. Another price is 22.74'.match(/(?=^|\.\s)\D+\d+(\.\d+)?(?=.|$)/gmu)
```

What this tells to JS RegExp engine:

> Dear Engine,
>
> Please, find something directly preceded by start of string or a dot & a space without including it in result.
>
> After that there should be one or more non-numbers.
>
> Then there should be one or more numbers that might be followed by a dot and one or more numbers.
>
> Finally, all that should be located just before end of string or a dot. Please, include neither in the result.
>
> Search for this pattern globally, in multiline mode & be aware of any unicode characters should there be any in the search string.

Comment: This is a great explanation, thank you! Was watching the coding train's youtube video on it as well